# How to install InlelliJ IDEA on Windows 7 32 bit?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I worked in Eclipse Oxygen 3 and wanna switch to Intellij idea now.

I've installed `JetBrains TOOLBOX` it doesn't include 32 bit version.

Comment: How you install anything in windows, just go to their website and download the 32-bit installer

Comment: There is no 32-bit installer for IDEA @NotZack

Comment: @grooveplex not a supported one I guess he has to use archives

Comment: While your question is clear, at first glance @NotZack's comment seems to be correct answer. But if problem is not actually related to *installation process* but rather with *finding proper installer* you should include that info in your question to avoid confusion (and downvotes caused by it).

Comment: Also I am curious if you tried downloading their standard installer. Maybe it also includes 32-bit version support but doesn't mention it?

Comment: @Pshemo I've installed JetBrains TOOLBOX it doesn't include 32 bit version

Comment: @EmotionalFerret I added that statement to your question. Feel free to [edit] it out if you don't agree with that change.

Answer (score 2):

Please try [ideaIU-2019.2-jbr8.exe](https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2019.2-jbr8.exe) version.

Since 2019.2, the IDE uses Java 11 runtime which no longer supports 32-bit Windows.

You should be able to still run IntelliJ IDEA on Java 8 runtime. 32-bit version can be found at [JetBrains JBR Bintray](https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jbr) repository and you can switch to it per [Switch boot JDK](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, unfortunately. The system requirements as listed on [the download page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows) are:

> - 64-bit versions of Microsoft Windows 10, 8, 7 (SP1)
> - 2 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended
> - 2.5 GB hard disk space, SSD recommended
> - 1024x768 minimum screen resolution

Comment: Depends on the Java version. Older versions do support 32 bit.